# InApp Billing: Caller uid is different

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to implement InApp billing. When I open the Play Store on my HTC Desire running (custom rom, rooted) GB, I get a message "An error occured, please try again". In the logcat, it says this:

```
08-04 19:58:59.920: I/ActivityManager(178): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cmp=com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.activities.IabActivity (has extras) } from pid -1
08-04 19:58:59.940: I/dalvikvm(1274): Could not find method android.accounts.AccountManager.newChooseAccountIntent, referenced from method com.google.android.finsky.activities.AuthenticatedActivity.chooseAccount
08-04 19:58:59.940: W/dalvikvm(1274): VFY: unable to resolve static method 7: Landroid/accounts/AccountManager;.newChooseAccountIntent (Landroid/accounts/Account;Ljava/util/ArrayList;[Ljava/lang/String;ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/os/Bundle;)Landroid/content/Intent;
08-04 19:58:59.940: D/dalvikvm(1274): VFY: replacing opcode 0x77 at 0x0021
08-04 19:58:59.940: D/dalvikvm(1274): VFY: dead code 0x0024-0029 in Lcom/google/android/finsky/activities/AuthenticatedActivity;.chooseAccount (Z)V
08-04 19:58:59.950: I/dalvikvm(1274): Could not find method com.google.android.finsky.activities.AuthenticatedActivity.recreate, referenced from method com.google.android.finsky.activities.AuthenticatedActivity.restart
08-04 19:58:59.950: W/dalvikvm(1274): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2843: Lcom/google/android/finsky/activities/AuthenticatedActivity;.recreate ()V
08-04 19:58:59.950: D/dalvikvm(1274): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0009
08-04 19:59:00.090: D/ResourceType(1274): calling getConfigurations
08-04 19:59:00.090: D/ResourceType(1274): called getConfigurations size=321
08-04 19:59:00.251: I/ActivityManager(178): Displayed com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.activities.IabActivity: +318ms
08-04 19:59:00.271: D/Finsky(1274): [1] DownloadImpl.setState: self-update-download from null to UNQUEUED.
08-04 19:59:00.271: D/Finsky(1274): [1] DownloadQueueImpl.add: Download self-update-download added to DownloadQueue
08-04 19:59:00.281: D/Finsky(1274): [1] DownloadImpl.setState: self-update-download from UNQUEUED to QUEUED.
08-04 19:59:00.341: I/installd(136): free_cache(0) avail 249487360
08-04 19:59:00.421: D/dalvikvm(1274): GC_CONCURRENT freed 909K, 50% free 3393K/6727K, external 2025K/2118K, paused 4ms+3ms
08-04 19:59:00.531: D/Finsky(1274): [1] DownloadQueueImpl.startDownload: Download self-update-download starting
08-04 19:59:00.651: D/Finsky(1274): [1] GetBillingCountriesAction.run: Skip getting fresh list of billing countries.
08-04 19:59:00.651: D/Finsky(1274): [1] DownloadImpl.setState: self-update-download from QUEUED to DOWNLOADING.
08-04 19:59:00.651: D/Finsky(1274): [1] DownloadQueueImpl.notifyProgress: self-update-download: onProgress 0/-1 Status: 190.
08-04 19:59:00.681: D/Finsky(1274): [1] DownloadQueueImpl.onStart: self-update-download: onStart
08-04 19:59:00.691: W/Finsky(1274): [1] CarrierParamsAction.run: Saving carrier billing params failed.
08-04 19:59:00.701: D/Finsky(1274): [1] CarrierProvisioningAction.shouldFetchProvisioning: Required CarrierBillingParams missing. Shouldn't fetch provisioning.
08-04 19:59:00.711: D/Finsky(1274): [1] CarrierProvisioningAction.run: No need to fetch provisioning from carrier.
08-04 19:59:00.721: W/AccountManagerService(178): caller uid 10005 is different than the authenticator's uid
08-04 19:59:00.721: E/Volley(1274): [32] 1.run: Caught SecurityException: caller uid 10005 is different than the authenticator's uid
08-04 19:59:00.771: D/Finsky(1274): [1] CheckoutPurchase.onErrorReceived: Could not retrieve Checkout auth token: caller uid 10005 is different than the authenticator's uid
08-04 19:59:00.771: E/Finsky(1274): [1] CheckoutPurchase.setError: type=UNKNOWN, code=-1, message=An error occurred. Please try again.
08-04 19:59:00.861: D/Finsky(1274): [1] MarketBillingService.sendResponseCode: Sending response RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR for request 8575012147884887212 to com.haarman.inapptest.
08-04 19:59:00.901: D/Finsky(1274): [1] DownloadQueueImpl.notifyProgress: self-update-download: onProgress 0/-1 Status: 192.
```

On my Asus TF101 running (custom rom, rooted) ICS, it **does** work.
On an HTC One V running stock ICS, it **does** work.
On an HTC Legend running (custom rom, rooted) GB, it **does** work.

So only on my HTC Desire it doesn't, work, which, frankly, is my main device. I've tried to reset the device to factory defaults, but that didn't help.

What's happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the Play Store on my Desire didn't update automatically. It was running 3.5.x, I had to manually push 3.5.17 for it to work.